# Faster way to transpose each row of a matrix and multiply the resulting vector by some other matrix?

Tags: matlab, loops, matrix, transpose

I have an input matrix `X` with dimensions `N_rows x N_cols`. I also have a sparse, tridiagonal matrix `M` which is square of size `N_rows x N_rows`. These are created as follows:

```
N_rows = 3;
N_cols = 6;
X = rand(N_rows,N_cols);

mm = 10*ones(N_cols,1); % Subdiagonal elements
dd = 20*ones(N_cols,1); % Main diagonal elements
pp = 30*ones(N_cols,1); % Superdiagonal elements
M = spdiags([mm dd pp],-1:1,N_cols,N_cols);
```

and look like the following:

```
>> X

X =

    0.4018    0.1233    0.4173    0.9448    0.3377    0.1112
    0.0760    0.1839    0.0497    0.4909    0.9001    0.7803
    0.2399    0.2400    0.9027    0.4893    0.3692    0.3897

full(M)

ans =

     2     3     0     0     0     0
     1     2     3     0     0     0
     0     1     2     3     0     0
     0     0     1     2     3     0
     0     0     0     1     2     3
     0     0     0     0     1     2
```

I would like to take each row of `X`, and do a matrix multiplication with `M`, and piece the obtained rows back together to obtain an output `Y`. At the moment, I achieve this successfully with the following:

```
Y = (M*X.').';
```

The example above is for a 3x6 matrix for `X`, but in reality I need to do this for a matrix with dimensions 500 x 500, about 10000 times, and the profiler says that this operation in the bottleneck in my larger code. Is there a faster way to do this row-by-row matrix multiplication multiplication?

On my system, the following takes around 20 seconds to do this 10000 times:

```
N_rows = 500;
N_cols = 500;
X = rand(N_rows,N_cols);

mm = 10*ones(N_cols,1); % Subdiagonal elements
dd = 20*ones(N_cols,1); % Main diagonal elements
pp = 30*ones(N_cols,1); % Superdiagonal elements
M = spdiags([mm dd pp],-1:1,N_cols,N_cols);

tic
for k = 1:10000
Y = (M*X.').';
end
toc

Elapsed time is 18.632922 seconds.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `X*M.'` instead of `(M*X.').';`. This saves around 35% of time on my computer.

This can be explained because transposing (or permuting dimensions) implies rearranging the elements in the internal (linear-order) representation of the matrix, which takes time.

Comment: This is great, excellent easy way to speed it up! Thank you. Do you think there are additional gains that could be made by taking advantage of the fact that the matrix is sparse? Secondly, I take it that loops are not the way to go here? Thanks again.

Comment: Making `X` a sparse tridiagonal matrix speeds things up a bit. (Those are the only values that contribute to the product.)

Comment: @teeeeee You are already defining `M` as sparse. I'm pretty sure that `*` automatically takes advantage of that

Answer (score 2):

Another option is using [`conv2`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/conv2.html):

```
Y = conv2(X, [30 20 10], 'same');
```

**Explanation:**
There is a tridiagonal matrix that all elements on each diagonal are identical to each other:

```
M = 
 2     3     0     0     0     0
 1     2     3     0     0     0
 0     1     2     3     0     0
 0     0     1     2     3     0
 0     0     0     1     2     3
 0     0     0     0     1     2
```

Suppose you want to multiply the matrix by a vector:

```
V = [11 ;12 ;13 ;14 ;15 ;16];
R = M * V;
```

Each element of the vector `R` is computed by sum of products of each row of `M` by `V`:

```
R(1):
 2     3     0     0     0     0
 11    12    13    14    15    16
R(2):
 1     2     3     0     0     0
 11    12    13    14    15    16
R(3):
 0     1     2     3     0     0
 11    12    13    14    15    16
R(4):
 0     0     1     2     3     0
 11    12    13    14    15    16
R(5):
 0     0     0     1     2     3
 11    12    13    14    15    16
R(6):
 0     0     0     0     1     2
 11    12    13    14    15    16
```

It is the same as multiplying a sliding window of `[1 2 3]` by each row of `M`. Basically convolution applies a sliding window but first it reverses the direction of window so we need to provide the sliding window in the reversed order to get the correct result. Because of that I used `Y = conv2(X, [30 20 10], 'same');` instead of `Y = conv2(X, [10 20 30], 'same');`.

Comment: This is actually slightly faster on my system than Luis Mendo's solution. Very clever! Can you explain a little how/why a 2D convolution provides a way to do this? I can't quite see it... You have also managed to do it entirely without using a sparse matrix... does that mean that your method only works if all elements on each diagonal are identical to each other?

Comment: @teeeeee Thanks, an explanation is added to the answer. It assumes that all elements on each diagonal are identical to each other as your provided example. Also there is no need to create the sparse matrix.

Comment: Thank you. Ofcourse, I see it now that a matrix multiplication is basically a series of scalar multiplications and integrations (summations) - now I see the connection to a convolution. Fantastic, very neat!